# how to send header:location to out of web root file

Tags: php, apache

I'm making a web application which will only allow registered members to download zip folders from a folders directory.

I really need  to know which would be the proper way to secure the folder as only members stored in my database will be able to access them so the problem is if somebody finds the directory and a file name there's nothing to stop them accessing it.

I've been doing some research and found some approaches but they all have major drawbacks.

1.) put the files outside of the webroot then use readfile to send them the data.
This is how I have it currently set up. the major draw back is that I'm on a shared server and max execution time for the script is 30 seconds (can't be changed) and if the file is big or user connection slow the timeout will be called before the download is complete.

2.) htaccess and htpasswd inside a webroot directory.

The problem with this is I don't want to have to ask the user to put a password again. unless there's a way to allow php to send the password then send a header to the actual zip file that needs to be downloaded.

3.) Keeping the files in webroot but obfuscating the file names so they are hard to guess.

this is just totally lame!

What I really would like to do is keep the files outside of web root then just send a header:location to that document to force a download, obviously as it's not in web root so the browser won't see it. is there a way around this. Is there a way to redirect to an out of web root file with  header:location('/file') to force a download. thus allowing apache to serve the file and not php with readfile.

Is there some easier way to secure the folders and serve with apache that I am just not coming across? Has anybody experienced this problem before and is there an industry standard way to do this better?

I know this may resemble a repeat question but none of the answers in the other similar question gave any useful information for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I really would like to do is keep the files outside of web root then just send a header:location to that document to force a download, obviously as it's not in web root so the browser won't see it.

More to the point, it is outside the web root so it *doesn't have a URL* that the server can send in the Location header.

> is there a way around this. Is there a way to redirect to an out of web root file with header:location('/file') to force a download.

No. Preventing the server from simply handing over the file is the *point* of putting it outside the web root. If you could redirect to it, then you would just be back in "hard to guess file name" territory with the added security flaw of *every file on the server* being public over HTTP.

> Is there some easier way to secure the folders and serve with apache that I am just not coming across.

Your options (some of which you've expressed already in the form of specific implementations) are:

- Use hard to guess URLs
- Put the file somewhere that Apache won't serve it by default and write code that will serve it for you
- Use Apache's own password protection options

There aren't any other approaches.

> Is there some easier way to secure the folders and serve with apache that I am just not coming across.

No, there isn't an easier way (but that said, all three implementations you've described are "very easy").

---

Another approach, which I consider really dirty but might get around your resource constraints:

- Keep the files outside the web root
- Configure Apache to follow symlinks
- On demand: Create a symlink from under the web root to the file you want to serve
- Redirect to the URI of that symlink
- Have a cron job running every 5 minutes to delete old symlinks (put a timestamp in the symlink filename to help with this)

It's effectively a combination of the first two options in my previously bulleted list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Quentin. yeah all three options are easy, i should have worded it better "is there a better way" . thanks for your clarification on the subject.  your seond point about putting the file locations where apache won't serve by defualt is interesting. if it's not to much trouble could you clarify what you mean by this. as i don't want to use htacsess psword as I said. and the hard to guess file names wouldn't stop a web ripper once it knows the parent directory.

Comment: If the file is in the web root. Then apache will give it a URI and server it. If it isn't, then apache won't.

Comment: Yeah but at some point I'm still going to have to reveal the parent directory URI. just out of interest of the three which way would you choose? with 282k points you obviously know what your talking about!

Comment: Well, normally, I'd go with the "Put the file somewhere that Apache won't serve it by default" approach, and (if I was stuck using PHP) use the `readfile` approach … but I've just seen your resource constraints (which are insanely tight).

Comment: well that's pretty much summed it up for me then thanks alot i can continue working on my project. I hate road blocks! It's great to get advice from somebody who's been there done that!

Comment: I've just added a dirty hack to the end of the answer

Comment: I'm gonna have to research these symlinks. another idea i thought of was fetching the whole file then copying it to a different directory inside webroot  then sending location header to there then deleting file after download but gets messy and hacky trying to determine when the file had been downloaded and was ready for deletion, not mention being more resource intensive. thanks for the heads up about  symlinks. It would be cheaper for me to just buy a dedicated server and use  set timeout to 0 than all the time Im dedicating to researching and testing on this subject.